# Can someone find an error with this code?

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I run this code in the browser, it says that there is no 'fadeIn' method. Is there a reason to it?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function showDiv1() {
        $("#blackback").fadeIn(500);
        $("#contactform").fadeIn(500);
        $("#blackback").click(function () {
            hideDiv1();
        });
    }
    function hideDiv1() {
        $("#blackback").fadeOut(500);
        $("#contactform").fadeOut(500);
    }
</script>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Are you properly adding jQuery to the page in a script tag above this?

Comment: Without seeing the accompanying markup it's hard to be certain but I'd say that the references to your elements are incorrect.

Comment: @Paul: Even if the selectors match no elements, that won't cause any error. Calling `fadeIn` on an empty jQuery object will just do nothing.

Comment: That code on its own won't actually do anything: you are declaring functions but not calling them. Are you sure the problem isn't in some other part of your code?

Comment: No the browser told me that it was on such and such a line!

Answer (score 1):

have you included jquery js ? like

```
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
```

refer http://api.jquery.com/delay/

Answer (score 1):

Two points

1. Like stated above, do you have the query library included?
2. When you're calling your functions, are you waiting for the dom to load before firing them, i.e. document ready?

I took your code and added in document ready and the jquery library and it seemed to work fine

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#blackback").hide();
            $("#contactform").hide();
            showDiv1();
        });

function showDiv1() {
$("#blackback").fadeIn(500);
$("#contactform").fadeIn(500);
$("#blackback").click(function () {
hideDiv1();
});
}
function hideDiv1() {
$("#blackback").fadeOut(500);
$("#contactform").fadeOut(500);
}
</script>

    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="blackback">ONE</div>
    <div id="contactform">contact Form</div>

    </body>

</html>
```

An example of this running is [here](http://www.dominic-green.com/examples/jqueryHide.html)

Answer (score 0):

It is jquery function, you have to register jquery javascript framework first